# PHP How to restructure an array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that I'd like to restructure. I want to group items by turn. I can figure out how to extract data from the array using `foreach($arr['history'] as $obj)`  my issue is with populating a new array using a loop.

Currently it looks like this:

```
Array ( 
[history] => Array ( 
    [id] => 23452435 
    [legend] => Array ( 

        [0] => Array ( 
            [player] => me 
            [turn] => 1 
            [card] => Array ( 
                [name] => foo 
            ) 
        ) 

        [1] => Array ( 
            [player] => me 
            [turn] => 1 
            [card] => Array ( 
                [name] => bar
            ) 
        ) 

        [2] => Array ( 
            [player] => opponent 
            [turn] => 1
            [card] => Array (
                [name] => derp 
            ) 
        ) 

        [3] => Array ( 
            [player] => opponent 
            [turn] => 2 
            [card] => Array ( 
                [name] => hoo
            ) 
        ) 
    ) 
))
```

I want it to look like the following, but I can't figure out how to automatically create and populate this structure. This is an array with a sub-array for each turn, containing an array for me and opponent

```
Array (
[0] => Array (
    [me] => Array (
        [0] => foo
        [1] => bar
    )
    [opponent] = Array (
        [0] => derp
    )

)
[1] => Array (
    [me] => Array ()
    [opponent] => Array (
        [0] => hoo
    )
))
```

Thanks.

**Edit:**

This is what I needed. Thanks for the answers.

```
$result = [];
foreach ($arr['history'] as $historyItem) {
  foreach ($historyItem['legend'] as $list) {
    $result[$list['turn']][$list['player']][] = $list['card']['name'];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$result = [];
foreach ($data['history']['legend'] as $list) {
  $result[$list['turn']-1][$list['player']][] = $list['card']['name'];
}
```

Fiddle it! http://ideone.com/BtKOKJ

Comment: This is what I needed. With a few adjustments I made it work for my dataset. Thanks :) Also for some reason I had to separate the foreach loop into two, one for each key.

Comment: Good method Naveed.  The one-liner (which I wrote before bothering to read your answer) looks like this:  `array_map(function($a)use(&$result){$result[$a["turn"]-1][$a["player"]][]=$a["card"]["name"];},$data["history"]["legend"]);`  Great minds intellectually converge!

Answer (score 1):

You can just start adding data to the new array. PHP is extremely forgiving.

```
$historyByTurns = array();
foreach ($arr['history'] as $historyItem) {
    foreach ($historyItem['legend'] as $legendItem) {
        $turn = $legendItem['turn'];
        $player = $legendItem['player'];
        if (!array_key_exists($turn, $historyByTurns)) {
            $historyByTurns[$turn] = array();
        }
        if (!array_key_exists($player, $historyByTurns[$turn])) {
            $historyByTurns[$turn][$player] = array();
        }
        foreach ($legendItem as $card) {
            $historyByTurns[$turn][$player][] = $card['name'];
        }
    }
}
```

You will have to test it, as I have no way to do that ATM.

Comment: This answer provided the same result as the other answer, but both weren't 100% what I needed, but helped me understand my issue. A few adjustments made this work though. Thanks :)